# Check computers on network for core isolation

Tags: windows, security, virtualization

Trying to find best method for checking all domain computers for core isolation being enabled. We have been slowly enabling this as new machines are deployed, but I would like to expedite the migration.

Normally powershell would be the way but I am not finding anything on the ol' google.

Comment: You may want to test this to see if there is any useful information between computers configured/not configured: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DeviceGuard -NameSpace root\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard`

Comment: @GregAskew That was what I was looking for, thanks.